# Do I have to stick to the length of stay mentioned to the immigration officer during my entry to the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I work remotely for a company in the US and I'm traveling next week to meet with the team along with some teambuilding. After that I'll return to my home country in South America. The company paid for a round-trip ticket from South America to the US with a 1 week stay in CO. I have a B1/B2 visa.

However, I'd like to do some tourism as well. Would it be safe to "miss" my flight home and instead fly to SFO or NYC and stay for an extra week? I'd buy another ticket to fly back home a week later. I have no intention whatsoever of overstaying of course.

I'm worried about immigration thinking I'm trying to overstay by missing my flight on purpose. Is my worry justified? Should I play it safe and just return in my original flight?

Comment: Why not rebook your flight home?  The change fees might be less expensive than buying a new ticket; you should at least inquire.  US immigration authorities won't care if you stay for 2 or 3 weeks instead of 1 week (unless for some very odd reason they give you only a 1-week period of admission), and whether you "miss" or reschedule your flight won't have any bearing on their opinion of the matter.

Comment: Rebooking is $1000+. A new ticket is $250-$300. Damn airlines...

Comment: What @phoog said. Also the immigration won't know nor care you missed your flight.

Comment: The B1/B2 visa *foresees* your desire to do tourism in this fantastic nation, and specifically includes tourism as a visa purpose.  That's what makes it a B1/B2 instead of just B1.  The B2 part is tourism.

Comment: @Harper actually it doesn't work that way.  Each time someone enters, the status is *either* B-1 or B-2, and tourism incident to a business trip is allowed in B-1 status, even if the traveler holds a B-1 visa instead of a B-1/B-2 visa.

Comment: Even if you don't rebook the flight home, why not just tell the border immigration officer that you plan on staying?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach makes no sense. Sort out your plane tickets before you leave and, when you arrive at immigration, tell them that you're staying for two weeks – one for business and one for tourism.